# Cleanly binding/unbinding to a Service in an Application

Tags: android, service, bind, unbind

I have an Android application that is binding to a persistent service (once started with `startService()`).

The service is an integral part of the application and thus is used in almost every Activity. Hence I want to bind to the service just once (instead of binding/unbinding in every Activity) and keep the binding during the lifetime of my application.

I've extended from [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and bind to the service in [Application#onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29). However I now have the problem that I don't know when my application exists since [Application#onTerminate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29) is never called, see JavaDoc:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never
>   be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed
>   by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is
>   executed when doing so.

So how do I cleanly unbind from a service bound in Application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this problem by counting the references to the service binding in the `Application`. Every `Activity` has to call `acquireBinding()` in their `onCreate()` methods and call `releaseBinding()` in `onDestroy()`. If the reference counter reaches zero the binding is released.

Here's an example:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    private final AtomicInteger refCount = new AtomicInteger();
    private Binding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // create service binding here
    }

    public Binding acquireBinding() {
        refCount.incrementAndGet();
        return binding;
    }

    public void releaseBinding() {
        if (refCount.get() == 0 || refCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            // release binding
        }
    }
}

// Base Activity for all other Activities
abstract class MyBaseActivity extend Activity {
    protected MyApp app;
    protected Binding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleState) {
        super.onCreate(savedBundleState);
        this.app = (MyApp) getApplication();
        this.binding = this.app.acquireBinding();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.app.releaseBinding();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your service survive screen rotations?

Comment: What do you mean? A Service in Android doesn't have a UI so it keeps running. In this case the Service was previously started with `context.startService()` and is marked sticky so it runs until it's manually stopped or stops itself.

Comment: I see. I was thinking that releasing the binding would stop the service, but not in this hybrid-service case. The binding is released in order to avoid a leaked service connection.

Comment: Correct. The service is started with `startService()` but also is bound to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

From Sven's answer:

> I solved this problem by counting the references to the service
>   binding in the Application. Every Activity has to call
>   acquireBinding() in their onCreate() methods and call releaseBinding()
>   in onDestroy(). If the reference counter reaches zero the binding is
>   released.

I agree, BUT you shouldn't do it in onDestroy - that will often not get called.

Instead I suggest the following (based on your code sample)...

```
// Base Activity for all other Activities
abstract class MyBaseActivity extend Activity {
    protected MyApp app;
    protected Binding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleState) {
        super.onCreate(savedBundleState);
        this.app = (MyApp) getApplication();
        this.binding = this.app.acquireBinding();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Pre-HC, activity is killable after this.
        if ((11 > Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) && (isFinishing()))
            onFinishing();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if ((10 < Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) && (isFinishing()))
            onFinishing();
    }

    protected void onFinishing() {
        // Do all activity clean-up here.
        this.app.releaseBinding();          
    }
}
```

BUT, my use of isFinishing() is just a thought - I'm not certain that it is reliable.  Perhaps onPause/onStop get called with isFinishing() false, but then the activity gets killed - and your releaseBinding() never gets called.

If you get rid of the isFinishing check I think you need to move the acquireBinding() call from onCreate to onStart/onResume (depending on sdk version), to ensure that your ref count doesn't get messed up.

Who knew that releasing your app's service would be so complicated!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will have a look at this. I also have the impression that my solution isn't reliable all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Is unbinding necessary at all in this case? The application gets killed anyway. I tried implementing a sample application doing this without unbinding and it seems to work properly.

Comment: If you don't unbind you should see "leaked service connection" errors in the logs.